# DbContext not saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It's been awhile since I have been playing with **DbContext**. I have been using a Serivce / Repository / UnitOfWork pattern for a number of years now, which has enabled me to use entity framework without worrying about how to add / update and delete.

Now I have decided that for some projects using that design pattern is not suitable (mainly when working with lookup tables). Because of this I have gone back to basics.

Using the **DbContext** has been find for getting information, but now I have actually started creating my methods for inserting / updating data I seem to have found an issue.
I am fairly certain that the issue is something simple, but I need some help :)

Here is my method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Import(IList<CollectionBindingModel> models)
{

    // If our ModelState is invalid, return a bad request
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    try
    {
        // Loop through our models
        foreach (var model in models)
        {

            // Create our collection
            var collection = new Collection()
            {
                CenterId = model.CenterId,
                Reference = model.Reference,
                CustomerReference = model.CustomerReference,
                CustomerName = model.CustomerName,
                CustomerBusinessName = model.CustomerBusinessName,
                SupplierName = model.SupplierName,
                CollectionCode = model.CollectionCode,
                Status = model.Status,
                CollectionDate = model.CollectionDate
            };

            // Add to our database context
            this.DbContext.Collections.Add(collection);
        }

        // Save our changes
        this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    // Return Ok
    return Ok();
}
```

I have merely added the try / catch block for testing purposes.
When I call this method from my interface, it returns OK and throws no errors, but if I check the database I see there have been no inserts.

Can anyone tell me why?

**Update 1**

So, digging a little deeper. I have a base controller which looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the creation of universal properties and methods
/// </summary>
public class BaseController : ApiController
{

    // Create our public properties
    protected DatabaseContext DbContext { get { return new DatabaseContext(); } }
    protected UserService UserService { get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); } }
    protected RoleService RoleService { get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<RoleService>(); } }
    protected ModelFactory ModelFactory { get { return new ModelFactory(this.Request, this.UserService); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to return the correct error from an Identity Result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The Identity Result to process</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
    {

        // If there is no result, return an internal server error
        if (result == null)
            return InternalServerError();

        // If we have an error
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {

            // If we have some errors
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {

                // For each error, add to the ModelState
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }

            // If our ModelState is valid
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                return BadRequest();
            }

            // Return a BadRequest with our ModelState
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Return null if no errors are found
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which is where the **DbContext** is pulled from.
If I change my controller method to this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Import(IList<CollectionBindingModel> models)
{

    // If our ModelState is invalid, return a bad request
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    try
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {

            // Loop through our models
            foreach (var model in models)
            {

                // Create our collection
                var collection = new Collection()
                {
                    CenterId = model.CenterId,
                    Reference = model.Reference,
                    CustomerReference = model.CustomerReference,
                    CustomerName = model.CustomerName,
                    CustomerBusinessName = model.CustomerBusinessName,
                    SupplierName = model.SupplierName,
                    CollectionCode = model.CollectionCode,
                    Status = model.Status,
                    CollectionDate = model.CollectionDate
                };

                // Add to our database context
                context.Collections.Add(collection);
            }

            // Save our changes
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }

    // Return Ok
    return Ok();
}
```

then everything saves OK.

Comment: You're not doing anything with caught exceptions?

Comment: So.. Remove the try-catch and look at the exception that is probably thrown?

Comment: What database are you using, by the way?

Comment: no, no exceptions are thrown even when the try / catch is removed. I added to just so I could put a breakpoint in the catch and nothing happens. In fiddler it returns a 200 response code.

Comment: using MSSQL (local). I know the dbcontext is working because I have using a database initializer to insert test data when the database does not exist.

Comment: I vaguely remember this sort of thing happening for a certain type of MSSQL due to a setting that shows you a different instance of the data than what the program sees. Have you tried reading the data via your code after rerunning it and seeing if the changes took place?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct database? EF6+ uses mssqllocaldb, not localdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are newing up a new DbContect everytime you access your DbContext property.**

Every time you access this.DbContext you get a new instance of the DbContext class because of the way you have set up your property...

```
protected DatabaseContext DbContext { get { return new DatabaseContext(); } }
```

So this line gets a new db context and adds the collection object... on the next itteration of this loop you will get ANOTHER new instance of DbContext and add the next one... you are NOT adding your collection classes to the same object instance...

```
// Add to our database context
this.DbContext.Collections.Add(collection);
```

And so does this...

```
 // Save our changes
        this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

That means you are basically calling save changes on a brand new instance of DbContext that has absolutely no changes. You should always add and attach your entities to the same instance of DbContext that you then call save changes on.

You have fixed the issue in your new code because you create a new DbContext instance in the constructor of your base class and then use that same instance throughout...

```
// Create our public properties
    protected DatabaseContext DbContext { get; private set; }
    protected UserService UserService { get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); } }
    protected RoleService RoleService { get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<RoleService>(); } }
    protected ModelFactory ModelFactory { get { return new ModelFactory(this.Request, this.UserService); } }

    public BaseController()
    {
        this.DbContext = new DatabaseContext();
    }
```

This would also work, when you access the property getter it will return the same instance if it has been initialised... or initialise it first and then return it...

```
private DatabaseContext _dbContext;

protected DatabaseContext DbContext
{
    get { return this._dbContext ?? (this._dbContext = new DatabaseContext()); }
}
```

Comment: your last line, would that actually return anything if this._dbContext is null or would it just set the context to something if it is null, but not actaully return anything?

Comment: It returns the instance if it is not null... if it IS null... it creates the instance AND then returns it :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I have fixed this but I have no idea why.

If I change my BaseController to this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the creation of universal properties and methods
/// </summary>
public class BaseController : ApiController
{

    // Create our public properties
    protected DatabaseContext DbContext { get; private set; }
    protected UserService UserService { get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserService>(); } }
    protected RoleService RoleService { get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<RoleService>(); } }
    protected ModelFactory ModelFactory { get { return new ModelFactory(this.Request, this.UserService); } }

    public BaseController()
    {
        this.DbContext = new DatabaseContext();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to return the correct error from an Identity Result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The Identity Result to process</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
    {

        // If there is no result, return an internal server error
        if (result == null)
            return InternalServerError();

        // If we have an error
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {

            // If we have some errors
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {

                // For each error, add to the ModelState
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }

            // If our ModelState is valid
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                return BadRequest();
            }

            // Return a BadRequest with our ModelState
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Return null if no errors are found
        return null;
    }
}
```

then everything works.
Note, that the only thing I have changed is moving the setting of the dbcontext to the constructor.
I suspect that it is because the way it was before, created a new database context every time someone requested it. This time it sets it on creation of the base controller.

Comment: must have been posting at the same time :D